# Script to convert unicode characters in <U9999> format to their ASCII equivalents

Tags: python, xml, bash, unicode

Im doing some changes in Linux locale files `/usr/share/i18n/locales` (like pt_BR), to change the default format of dates, time, numbers, etc. But since unicode chars are presented as strings in the `<U9999>` format, text is very hard to read.

Here is a snippet of it:

```
LC_TIME
abday   "<U0044><U006F><U006D>";"<U0053><U0065><U0067>";/
    "<U0054><U0065><U0072>";"<U0051><U0075><U0061>";/
    "<U0051><U0075><U0069>";"<U0053><U0065><U0078>";/
    "<U0053><U00E1><U0062>"
```

So, how to make a simple script (may be bash, python, pearl, whatever) to convert this text replacing the `<Uxxxx>` codes to their ASCII equivalents? (yes, they are all ASCI chars below 255, most even below 127)

If several answers are received, Ill accept the most elegant and/or the more detailed explained one (like options and flags used in comands)

As an example, the above text would be converted to:

```
LC_TIME
abday   "Dom";"Seg";/
    "Ter";"Qua";/
    "Qui";"Sex";/
    "Sáb"
```

Bonus points for another script that could do the opposite: convert all chars of a given string to `<Uxxx>` format.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there are tools in the XML pantheon of utilties that could handle this much  better. I recommend you tag this post with XML (maybe XSLT too?). Good luck!

Comment: The Unicode notation is used because not all Unicode characters have an ASCII equivalent.  So, what do you want done with Unicode sequences that don't have an ASCII equivalent (which is the majority of Unicode sequences - by the number of possible sequences; not necessarily the majority by the number of used sequences).

Comment: Characters U0080 to U00FF (i.e. decimal from 128 to 255) inclusive are **NOT** ASCII. They would have to be converted using an encoding of your choice, probably `latin1` in your case.

Comment: @shelter: Ok, ive added the tag. Are there any tools in simple linux scripting (bash, python, etc) that handle XML?

Comment: @Jonathan/John: true, but in that file (pt_BR) 99% of the unicode used is actually asci chars between U0020 and U0079. Very few is between 80 and FF, and none is above FF. So they would be perfectly printable in my system. I dont mind if a few characters go wrong, as long as 99% of the text becomes human readable. Its **very** time-consuming to check an ASCI table, char by char, just to decode strings like "%d %Y %z %HH:%MM", or "%d-%m-%Y", or "Saturday". I would like to change date, currency formats, but it would take hours to decode, and then re-encode. Hence the need for a script  to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using Fields

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'<U0+|>' '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i ~ "^[0-9A-F]+$")
            $i=sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x"$i))
}1' OFS="" /path/to/infile
```

#### Explanation

1. `-F'<U0+|>'`: This is the magic that makes this script so short. We tell awk that the field separator is either `<U0+` or a simple `>`.  The benefit of doing this is that awk will auto-strip these characters for us so we don't have to do it manually with `gsub()` when it comes time to do the strtonum() conversion.
2. `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`: iterate over each field
3. `if($i ~ "^[0-9A-F]+$")`: check if the current field is only composed of hex digits. Remember that due to #1 above something like `<U006F>` will be seen as `6F` at this point
4. `$i=sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x"$i))`: replace the hex digit with its corresponding ascii value.  We must prefix the field `$i` with `"0x"` so awk knows its a hex value
5. `}1`: shortcut for a mandatory `print` or *always print each line*
6. `OFS=""`: set the Output Field Separator to the null string.  If we don't do this, we will get spaces in the output everywhere there was a `<U0+` or `>`

---

#### Using match() [requires gawk]

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk '{
    while(match($0, /<U[0-9A-F]+>/)){
        pat = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/U0+|[<>]/,"",pat)
        asc = sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x"pat))
        $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) asc substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}1' /path/to/infile
```

Comment: Looks great so far! Ill test it to see if it works. Care to explain the parameters used? Ive never played with awk command before. Also, i guess the reverse script would be even simpler (from "abcd" to "<U0040><U0041><U0042><U0043>"), since it doesnt need any regex matching.

Comment: @MestreLion: look at my new optimized version. I'll put notes on how it works

Comment: It worked! I changed /path/to/infile to "$1" and saved the script as "unicode-decode", tested with both "en_US" and "pt_BR", it worked perfectly for the 1st, and great for the other. Words like "Sábado" and "Março" became corrupted, but that was expected and its no big deal (I only wish gedit was not so picky about this, it refused to open the file), but i could cat the results and read on screen, so its fine.

Comment: +1 for the optimization. And now chars between 80 and FF do not corrupt the on-screen result (terminal shows them as a single "?" char in black-on-white), and gedit accepts the text and shows the right character perfectly!!! AWESOME!!!

Comment: @MestreLion: glad it worked out for you, not bad for < 100 chars of awk code eh? =).  I also added an explanation section in case that's helpful to you or whomever will read this.

Comment: Amazing answer and awesome explanation. Your detailed breakdown allowed me to understand each character of that sweet, smart little script. And helped me learn a ton about awk (sooooo much more friendly then sed!).

Comment: Stay tuned as I will now create a new question for the reverse script. And again, thank you very much!

Comment: @MestreLion: if you post another question about the reverse script and write another well-written question with sample input and desired output I'll attempt to answer that as well.

Comment: There ya go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527981/script-to-convert-ascii-chars-to-uxxx-unicode-notation

Comment: @MestreLion: got it.  Answer [*HERE*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527981/script-to-convert-ascii-chars-to-uxxx-unicode-notation/5528045#5528045).  It was bit more complicated due to the fact that you only want to do unicode transliteration between double-quotes.  If you wanted to do it to *every* character then it would have been a simple one-liner.

Comment: I got this error: awk: line 6: function strtonum never defined. Solved it by installing gawk and changing awk to gawk

Comment: @SiegeX I used the first example. Did not try the second one

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script in Python that converts `<U9999>` strings to their ASCII (0-127) equivalent using [`unidecode` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput, re, sys
from unidecode import unidecode # to install, run: $ pip install unidecode

for line in fileinput.input(inplace='--inplace' in sys.argv):
    print re.sub(r'<U([0-9A-F]{4})>',
                 lambda m: unidecode(unichr(int(m.group(1), 16))),
                 line),
```

It accepts input from stdin and/or files given at command-line.

```
$ u9999-to-ascii data.in
LC_TIME
abday   "Dom";"Seg";/
    "Ter";"Qua";/
    "Qui";"Sex";/
    "Sab"
```

Note, there is no `á` character due to ascii doesn't support it, so the script replaced it by its ascii analog `a`.

If you don't need ascii then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput, re, sys

for line in fileinput.input(mode='rb', inplace='--inplace' in sys.argv):
    print(re.sub(br'<U([0-9A-F]{4})>', lambda m: br'\u'+m.group(1),
                 line).decode('raw-unicode-escape'), end='')
```

This script works in both Python2.6+ and Python3.x. Example:

```
$ u9999-to-unicode.py data.in
LC_TIME
abday   "Dom";"Seg";/
    "Ter";"Qua";/
    "Qui";"Sex";/
    "Sáb"
```

Note, there is `á`. This script might produce an error if your terminal encoding doesn't support all Unicode characters from `data.in`.  You could use [`.encode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method in this case.