# Script to convert ASCII chars to "<Uxxx>" unicode notation

Tags: python, string, bash, ascii

I'm doing some changes in Linux locale files `/usr/share/i18n/locales` (like `pt_BR`), and it's required that format strings (like `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M`) must be specified in Unicode, where each (in this case, ASCII) character is represented as `<U00xx>`.

So a text like this:

```
LC_TIME
d_t_fmt "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
d_fmt   "%d-%m-%Y"
t_fmt   "%T"
```

Must be:

```
LC_TIME
d_t_fmt "<U0025><U0061><U0020><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0025><U0062><U0020><U0025><U0059><U0020><U0025><U0054><U0020><U0025><U005A>"
d_fmt   "<U0025><U0064><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0059>"
t_fmt   "<U0025><U0054>"
```

Thus I need a command-line script (be it bash, Python, Perl, or something else) that would take an input like `%d-%m-%Y` and convert it to `<U0025><U0064><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0059>`.

All characters in the input string would be ASCII chars (from `0x20` to `0x7F`), so this is actually a fancier "char-to-hex-string" conversion.

Could anyone please help me? My skills in bash scripting are very limited, and even worse in Python.

Bonus for elegant, explained solutions.

Thanks!

(by the way, this would be the "reverse" script for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527122/))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Every char with file input

If you wanted to convert *every* character of a file to the unicode representation, then it would be this simple one-liner

```
while IFS= read -r -n1 c;do printf "<U%04X>" "'$c"; done < ./infile
```

---

#### Every char on STDIN

If you want to make a unix-like tool which converts input on STDIN to unicode-like output, then use this:

```
uni(){ c=$(cat); for((i=0;i<${#c};i++)); do printf "<U%04X>" "'${c:i:1}"; done; }
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ echo "abc" | uni
<U0061><U0062><U0063>
```

---

#### Only chars between double-quotes

```
#!/bin/bash

flag=0
while IFS= read -r -n1 c; do
    if [[ "$c" == '"' ]]; then
        ((flag^=1))
        printf "%c" "$c"
    elif [[ "$c" == $'\0' ]]; then
        echo
    elif ((flag)); then
        printf "<U%04X>" "'$c"
    else
        printf "%c" "$c"
    fi
done < /path/to/infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat ./unime
LC_TIME
d_t_fmt "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
d_fmt   "%d-%m-%Y"
t_fmt   "%T"
abday "Dom";"Seg";/
here is a string with "multiline
quotes";/

$ ./uni.sh
LC_TIME
d_t_fmt "<U0025><U0061><U0020><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0025><U0062><U0020><U0025><U0059><U0020><U0025><U0054><U0020><U0025><U005A>"
d_fmt   "<U0025><U0064><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0059>"
t_fmt   "<U0025><U0054>"
abday "<U0044><U006F><U006D>";"<U0053><U0065><U0067>";/
here is a string with "<U006D><U0075><U006C><U0074><U0069><U006C><U0069><U006E><U0065>
<U0071><U0075><U006F><U0074><U0065><U0073>";/
```

#### Explanation

Pretty simply really

1. `while IFS= read -r -n1 c;`: Iterate over the input one character at a time (via `-n1`) and store the char in the variable `c`.  The `IFS=` and `-r` flags are there so that the `read` builtin doesn't try to do word splitting or interpret escape sequences, respectively.
2. `if [[ "$c" == '"' ]];`: If the current char is a double-quote
3. `((flag^=1))`: Invert the value of flag from 0->1 or 1->0
4. `elif [[ "$c" == $'\0' ]];`: If the current char is a NUL, then `echo` a newline
5. `elif ((flag))`: If flag is 1, then perform unicode transliteration
6. `printf "<U%04X>" "'$c"`: The magic that does the unicode transliteration. Note that the single-quote before the `$c` is mandatory as it tells `printf` that we are giving it the ASCII representation of a number.
7. `else printf "%c" "$c"`: Print out the character with no unicode transliteration performed

Comment: Wow, you actually managed to convert *only* the text between ""! Thats way more than what i needed, cool! The one-liner, "convert every char" was what i asked for. +1 for the detailed explanation and also for providing even more than asked for. Ill test both now

Comment: I was curious about your first, complete solution, so i tested it first, and it worked great. 2 minor issues: it got a little confused with lines like `abday "Dom";"Seg";/`, converting everything from the first " till the end of line, except the " themselves (but including ; and ;/). Also, it didnt convert lines "multiline" strings where the closing " was 2 (or 3) lines away. NO, dont bother to fix that, since multiline strings was NOT part of the question, and a regex to solve that would be far beyond the scope. But a fix for `aaaa "bbb";"ccc";/` pattern would be appreciated.

Comment: @MestreLion You *can't* solve nested quotes with regex. See [HERE](http://www.texttoolkit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63%3aparsing-balanced-parenthesis-with-regular-expressions&catid=35%3atechnology&Itemid=55). But I can (and will) fix the non-multiline,non-nested problem

Comment: Dont bother... i studied the code, and just changed `flag=1` to `if ((flag)); then flag=0; else flag=1; fi`, and it worked.

Comment: @MestreLion: ya, but turns out the fix for multiline quotes is fairly simple too.  See updated code & explanation

Comment: They are not nested (yes, those would be cruel), they are only opened and closed several times a line. As for multiline, since `read` only works line- or char-based, it will never catch those. No big deal, since originally i just asked for a simple "invoke script, type in some string, press enter, voila" solution

Comment: @MestreLion: actually, looks like you had it, my version with XOR is just a much more compact way of doing what you did.  Also, you need to remove the `flag=0` part if a NUL is found.

Comment: @MestreLion: *"it will never catch those"*, I believe my new version *does* catch those. See the new **Proof of Concept** text.  Is that not what you consider multiline?

Comment: wow, is `((flag^=1))` a... bash toggle??? Omg, thats sweet! And yes, i didnt realize that removing the `flag=0` from NUL block would also fix the multiline "issue".

Comment: @MestreLion: ya, only works if you know flag will be as high as `1` otherwise you'll need to do `((flag=!flag))`.  In case you didn't already know, bash can do the set to self shortcut with other operators as well.

Comment: I tweaked the "complete" solution a lil bit further to handle the special case of "/" being a scape char for multi-line, and it shouldnt be converted even when enclosed inside a "" pair. (meaning 1 more elif block with a printf "/"). Now ill try the STDIN solution. Btw, is there any way of any of those can be adjusted to a simpler "invoke script, type in some string, press enter, print conversion" approach?

Comment: @Mestre: hmm, the forward slash `/` is usually the line-continuation character not the backslash `\ `. In any case, regarding the last question, are you looking to do that with converting every char or the "complete" solution?

Comment: Based in your STDIN solution, I tweaked to `read c; for((i=0;i<${#c};i++)); do printf "<U%04X>" "'${c:i:1}"; done; echo` and it worked perfectly. Thanks for all the input, I learned a LOT about bash, python and awk for a single nite. Its time for some serious locale customization now ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Using Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2
import sys
text = sys.argv[1]
encoded = "".join("<U{0:04X}>".format(ord(char)) for char in text)
print(encoded)
```

Usage:

```
$ python3 file.py "enter_input"
<U0065><U006E><U0074><U0065><U0072><U005F><U0069><U006E><U0070><U0075><U0074>
```

(The same script should work for both python 3.x and 2.x. Just change the version in shebang 
to the one you have.)

Explanation:

1. We need to import [the `sys` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html) to read the command-line arguments.
2. The [`sys.argv` list](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is the list of all command-line arguments. The entry [0] is the program name, entry [1] is the first argument, etc.
3. `f(char) for char in text` is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). It will loop for each character in the `text` variable, then apply the function `f` on it, and finally collect the result as a lazy list ([iterable](http://docs.python.org/py3k/glossary.html#term-iterable)).
4. [`ord(char)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#ord) finds the Unicode code-point of the character.
5. [`"<U{0:04X}>".format(x)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is a string formatting method as described by the name. The format string takes 1 input `x`, and format into the [`04X` format](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#formatspec), meaning leading-zero, width-4, uppercase-hexadecimal.
6. [`"".join(it)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) concatenates all elements in the lazy list (iterable) `it`. The `""` means the separator is an empty string.
7. [`print(encoded)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#print) write the string `encoded` to stdout.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. What a great phyton lesson! :) Ill test it right away.

Comment: It didnt work, somthing to do with the shebang: /usr/bin/env: python 3.2: No such file or directory. Changing from "python3.2" to "python" also gave error (when tested with aaa). Shall i use a string or a filename? Can it be changed to accept command-line argument? Like `encode "aaaa"`

Comment: @MestreLion: Probably you haven't installed python3.2. Try to change it to python3.1, or use the Python 2.x version at the end.

Comment: @KennyTM: although a nice python script, I'm going to have to -1 this because it does not produce the output that the OP requests. Yours unilaterally converts *every* char to unicode.

Comment: Well, now that its fixed, it does produce what I want. I guess my question was not so well-formulated this time. I just wanted to provide little strings (the "" was just to delimiter it, and allow spaces in input, but it wasnt mandatory) and the script would convert every char of it. This way I could change the date and currency formats used in my previous question file, to a custom one, by copy-and-paste my modifications.

Comment: Comparing the fixed and the previous script, i now realize what was the error: looks like python demands that input is ""-delimited even when reading from stdin. So aaa do not work while "aaa" worked. Its weird for it to demand using "" when in 'user-input mode'. Meaning i couldnt use it with pipes, either echo (string) or cat (file)

Comment: Hi thereI am trying your script with greek characters and its produces some ASCII unicode codes, but not the expected ones: `./encodeUstr πμ` (πμ in case you can't see it is the greek chars for PM , post meridiem). The answer I get is `<U00CF><U0080><U00CE><U00BC>`, from a unicode table  I expect: <U03C0><U+03BC>. Why do I even get 4 characters in your case instead of just 2?

Comment: @nass: Did you run it on Python 2.x? The same script returns `<U03C0><U03BC>` on Python 3.x and `<U00CF><U0080><U00CE><U00BC>` on Python 2.x. To get the 3.x behavior in 2.x, you can replace `sys.argv[1]` with `sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')` (assuming you're using UTF-8 on your terminal where you run the script).

Answer (score 0):

`echo -n "aä" | ruby -KU -e '$<.chars{|c| print "<U"+"%04X"%c.unpack("U*")[0]+">"}; puts'`

Outputs `<U0061><U00E4>`

`-KU` = `$KCODE = "U"`

Answer (score 0):

Shell script solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r -n1 c;
    do printf "<U%04X>" "'$c";
done
```

This reads standard input and prints to standard output (assuming you've put the script into the executable file *toUnicode.sh*):

```
> echo "hello" | toUnicode.sh
<U0068><U0065><U006C><U006C><U006F><U0000>
```

This does print the EOF character (the `<U0000>`), but you can alter this script to suit your needs, whether you want to read the input one line at a time or trim it or alter it another way.

Comment: This seems identical to the accepted answer first solution

Comment: I upvoted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528045/393280), but the presentation of the tool sample ("**Every character on STDIN**") confused me. I was trying to make a generic tool, and while the answer provided some guidance, I spent a good deal of time trying to determine why the answerer presented his tools in that way. I wanted to save anyone else in my position the confusion I experienced.